# Drop-down select instead of selection box in custom field widget

Tags: entities

I am creating a custom field for phone numbers. The field creates a phone record that contains the type of phone contact (work, home, etc), as well as the number and an extension... much like Apple's "Contacts" app.

The problem I am having is for the phone type drop-down list. Instead of showing a nice drop-down select list like this example of a publishing status...

[image: dropdown list]

I end up with a selection box like this...

[image: selection box]

Here is what my hook_field_widget_info() looks like...

```
/**
 * Implements hook_field_widget_form().
 */
function MYMODULE_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element) {

  $element['label'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => drupal_map_assoc(array(
      t('home'),
      t('work'),
      t('main'),
      t('mobile'),
      t('other'),
    )),
    '#size' => 12,
    '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]['label']) ? $items[$delta]['label'] : 'home',
  );

  $element['number'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Number'),
    '#size' => 16,
    '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]['number']) ? $items[$delta]['number'] : '',
  );

  $element['ext'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#field_prefix' => t('ext'),
    '#size' => 6,
    '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]['ext']) ? $items[$delta]['ext'] : '',
  );

  $element['primary'] = array(
    '#type' => 'ckeckbox',
    '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]['primary']) ? $items[$delta]['primary'] : 0,
    '#return_value' => 1,
  );

  return $element;
}
```

I can see how the selection box style select element can be useful for multiple selects, but this is just a single select. I'd like to see a drop-down element. I must be missing something here, but I haven't figured out what it could be. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out and it was much easier than I thought... It's the "size" attribute. I deleted the size attribute, ('#size' => 12,), and I have a drop-down select list. I suppose it just came to posting the question here for me to figure it out on my own. :P